# Dynamic Radio Buttons 2 Way Binding using ngModel - Angular 6

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-ngmodel

I'm generating dynamic radio buttons which will all be consolidated on form submit not individually. I however need to bind them to a particular value in my component individually which I have no clue how to do.

I've seen the other related posts on this subject on stackoverflow but none of them seem to help me out.

Here's my code:

```html
<input type="radio" class="one" id="{{ i }}_{{ candidate.user._id }}_{{post.id}}_{{ candidate.date}}" name="{{post.id}}" [value]='candidate.user._id' [(ngModel)]="post.id">
<label for="{{ i }}_{{ candidate.user._id }}_{{post.id}}_{{ candidate.date }}">
    <span>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
    </span>
</label>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it already bind to a particular value with post.id? Not sure to understand what you want, but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039380/5049472) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a new variable of an array in component :

```
private radioButtonValues : Array<any> = [];
```

then bind it in you ngModel with index `i` as :

```
<input type="radio" class="one" 
       id="{{ i }}_{{ candidate.user._id }}_{{post.id}}_{{ candidate.date}}" 
       name="{{post.id}}" 
      [value]='candidate.user._id' 
      [(ngModel)]="radioButtonValues[i]">
```

if you want some manipulation you can also use `ngModelChange` event for more functionality.

```
<input type="radio" class="one" 
       id="{{ i }}_{{ candidate.user._id }}_{{post.id}}_{{ candidate.date}}" 
       name="{{post.id}}" 
       [value]='candidate.user._id' 
       [(ngModel)]="radioButtonValues[i]" 
       (ngModelChange)='changeEventInRadioButton($event)'>
```

then declare function in your component class

```
changeEventInRadioButton($event) {
    console.log($event);
}
```

at last on form submission check

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.radioButtonValues);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nasiruddin Saiyed, index in the ngModel fixed it. Though I had to use public radioButtonValues : Array<any> = []; to make it accessible